# Javascript: Add margin to the element if another element is higher than X pixels inside an object. Multiple objects on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object (div) which has two elements (with classes) inside.

Task: When height of the element A is lower than 40px then add to element B 22px margin-top.

However there are many objects on the page and the following code just finds the first element A (has class .list name) and adds margin to all elements B (has class .product-image-container).

```
if ($('.list-name').height() < 40) {

    $('.product-image-container').css('margin-top','22px');
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Rob

Comment: can you add your html?

Comment: When you use jQuery selector `$()` it always brings an array of element objects, even if it is just one. If you have more than one `.product-image-container`, it will always bring all of then and set things to all. We need your html to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your required solution,

- Loop though the all `list-name` classes using `$('.list-name').each()` function.
- Get the next `product-image-container` closer to it using `(obj).next('.product-image-container')`
- Change the css of that whatever you need like, `$(obj).next('.product-image-container').css('margin-top', '20px')`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list-name').each(function(index, obj){
    console.log($(obj).height())
    if($(obj).height() > 20)
    {
       $(obj).next('.product-image-container').css('background', 'green')
    }
    });
    

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <div class="list-name" style="height: 20px">list-name 1</div>
  <div class="product-image-container">product-image-container 1</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="list-name" style="height: 40px">list-name 2</div>
  <div class="product-image-container">product-image-container 2</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**Here is a Working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/NrjQdYJBpgzdq3sRFe4I?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, your solution works great. However to implement it to my web I found out that it only works for the next div inside the object and my object actually has three divs that div is between element A and element B so this solution does not work for that. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Since you haven't added any `html`, I assumed your `html` and written the answer. Add the html and I ll update my answer accordingly.